# Increase priority of execution for an Airflow DAG?

Tags: queue, task, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Airflow has a queuing mechanism to execute queued tasks, and it does this across all the dags. I have a specific DAG which is high priority, meaning if there a task from this DAG scheduled and queued to run, I want it to be processes high priority. Is there a way to instruct airflow to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow consider priority of tasks when scheduling thus you can use [priority weight](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/priority-weight.html) to increase the ranking of specific tasks. Note that this is not a DAG parameter but an Operator parameter. If you wish to apply it to all tasks in a specific DAG use `default_args`.

Example:

```
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.weight_rule import WeightRule
BashOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    bash_command="echo 1",
    weight_rule=WeightRule.ABSOLUTE,
    priority_weight=10000,
)
```

You can change the `weight_rule` & `priority_weight` according to what you wish.